# JSF2 redirect issue

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I have login page and dashboard page.

As soon as login process done dashboard page (using navigation rule) will be displayed.

```
  <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/login.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>dashboard</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/viewp/dashboard.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
```

I have filter mapping for all requests.

Here is my scenario, There is client side poller on my dashboard page. When server restarts, poller sends request which will be interpreted by Filter.

Inside Filter I have logic like

```
If(url.contains("login.xhtml))
{
//dofilter
}else
{
// redirect to login.
}
```

but somehow this is not redirecting.

One observation I have is, after login even though I am on dashboard page, my URL still is like `mydomain/login.xhtml`. I think because URL in browser is `mydomain/login.xhtml`, `response.redirect("mydomain/login.xhtml")` is not working. Any suggestions?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The poller is executed by JavaScript/Ajax, right? Well, you've got to check in JavaScript/Ajax if the server returned a 302 instead of 200 and handle accordingly. The browser itself doesn't do that automatically for returned JavaScript/Ajax responses, but only for responses on synchronous requests.

You can use `window.location` in JavaScript to perform a "redirect". E.g.

```
if (ajaxResponseStatus == 302) {
    window.location = newURL;
}
```

Comment: Instead of server response, what I am trying to do is, when server is up and poller sends request, it will go through Filter, inside filter I am able to findout that it is first request, so doing send.redirect(). But the problem is the URL I pass here is exact same as what I have already in browser, I guess that is why browser not doing anything.

Comment: Are you now saying that you're synchronously polling? Your question/problem makes only sense if you're doing it asynchronously (i.e. by JavaScript/Ajax).

Comment: Is there anyway when we move from login.xhtml to dashboard.xhtml we can change broswer url based on navigation rule like in my question? I tried /viewp/dashboard.xhtml?faces-redirect=true also.

Comment: It is a4j:poll, so it is asynchronous call.

Comment: Well, just let its callback function handle the redirect then (if that component supports it).

Comment: hmmm, callback function of a4j:poll? I don't think there is anything available for that. Let me check.

Comment: Why, when navigation rule is executed and dashboard is displayed, still url showing as login.xhtml only? Any idea?

Comment: Because it's a forward, not a redirect. Add `<redirect/>` to it. But that isn't your concrete problem, right?

Comment: I think this solves the issue. Because the flow is like this, 1)enter  login url in browser 2) Filter checks is it login or not, if login continues otherwise checks for session and another logged user related variable, if they exists, process continues 3) If session is brand new but not login, it redirects to login. Now, I entered valid credentials, logged in to dashboard. a4j:poller code is in dashboard page. It continues execution on certain interval and now browser url will be login.xhtml.

Comment: All of sudden assume server down. When a4j:poller continues polling, when server is  up, next a4j:poller request will be processed by Filter (remember url in browser is login.xhtml). Based on third condition in above comment, now Filter redirects to login.xhtml and subsequent call executes First condition in above comment, But page still displays dashboard page only, login page is not being displayed.  That is the issue. But I guess it is because browser already have login.xhtml in url, so redirect is being ignored. I may be wrong too. What do you suggest?

Comment: Because of my assumption that browser ignoring response.redirect() because of both urls are same, I am feeling having <redirect/> in navigation rule may resolve the issue. I will try this as soon as I login tomorrow morning.

Comment: It won't. The `<a4j:poll>` doesn't react to redirected responses. That's your concrete problem.

Comment: ahh! really? Then I am in big mess. What else we could do here?

Comment: If all the poller needs to do is to invoke that filter (and thus no JSF artifacts/components), you could as good use jQuery's `$.get()` which is exeucted by `setInterval()`. In the `$.get()` callback, just check response status code.

Comment: Ok. Let me try that as soon as I login in morning. Thanks for your time on this thread BalusC.